# Links invisible on post notices

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The post notices with a link look like this:

[image: post notice]

The words "Good Subjective, Bad Subjective" are a link but it looks exactly like the rest of the text except on hover.

Also, see [this closed question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8669/why-is-homo-sapiens-is-the-only-intelligent-species) for another example; "faq" is a link, but indistinguishable as such.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This has been fixed. This does however add an underline to the User name, and as it has no class name on the link, it will be different than where other user names appear.

Please note that and do not report the User name being underlined as a bug.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `.question-status p a {text-decoration: underline;}` to avoid also hitting the username? The user is in the h2 element and won't be affected by this rule.

Comment: `Good subjective, bad subjective` isn't a user name, is it? `FAQ` isn't a user name either.