# Links in post notices are invisible

Tags: bug, design

There are six links in the following image:

[image]

Except for the user name, all those links are invisible. [This was reported in the past and fixed](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/links-invisible-on-post-notices), but it seems the links are invisible again.